# What is a Bird city™?

Tags: pattern, geography

If a city conforms to a special rule, I call it a Bird city™.
Each city in the World can be tested. This is not a definitive list of Bird cities™.

| Bird cities™ | Not Bird cities™ |
| --- | --- |
| Paris - France | Bergamo - Italy |
| Osaka - Japan | Munich - Germany |
| New York - United States of America | San Francisco - United States of America |
| Bogota - Colombia | Seville - Spain |
| Marrakesh - Morocco | Liverpool - England |
| Oxford - England | Boston - United States of America |
| Savannakhet - Laos | Shanghai - China |
| Doha - Qatar | Lyon - France |
| Mykonos - Greece | Venice - Italy |

Find the rule which determines whether or not a city is called a Bird City™.

---

<sub>*Although it is a little inspired by the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), it is not exactly in the same spirit. In particular, there is no `word-property` tag.*</sub>

#### 21st of February, creating first hint

> I am planning to add a first hint which will double the number of examples. Please ask for cities you want me to tell whether they are Bird cities or not in comments and when the number of asked cities will reach 18, the first hint will be published.

#### First Hint 1 in progress

Note: I can't make my markdown table hint into spoiler, can you help please :D ?

| Bird cities™ | Not Bird cities™ |
| --- | --- |
| Jakarta - Indonesia @ophact - 21st of February | East Grestin - Russia @notalentgeek 22nd of February |
| Quebec City - Canada @Auribouros - 21s of February | Lutetia - Roman Empire @xyldke - 22nd of February |
| Cambridge - England and UK @quarague 21st of February | Bremen - Germany @xyldke - 25th of February |
| Amsterdam - Netherlands @notalengeek 22nd of February | Mylkolayiv - Ukraine 23rd of February |
| Gotham City - USA @notalengeek 22nd of February | Lviv - Ukraine 23rd of February |
| East and West Berlin - Germany - Cold War @Auribouros 24th of February | Odessa- Ukraine 23rd of February |
| Glasgow - Scotland @xyldke - 25th of February |  |
| Brooklyn - USA - 1897 @xyldke - 25th of February |  |
| New York City - USA - 1897 @xyldke - 25th of February |  |
| Roma - Italia @xyldke - 1st of March |  |
| Stormwind - World of Warcraft @Auribouros - 21st of June |  |

In the next table, I do not have enough knowledge to determine whether it is a Bird city™ or not.

| To be discovered later | Member and asking date |
| --- | --- |
| East Grestin - Arstotzka | @notalentgeek 22nd of February |

Note: I was asked several cities that do not exist anymore. Please note that although getting interested to pass Bird Cities is possible, there is no `history` tag in this puzzle :)

#### Second Hint 21st of June

> A Bird city™ may be called a Crow Flies city™

Comment: Is Jakarta, Indonesia a bird city?

Comment: Is Quebec City a Bird city ?

Comment: As for the markdown table being in a spoiler tag, this seems to be a bug (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359860/markdown-tables-in-spoilers), so I don't think there's a way to circumvent it, might have to make the hint a CSV instead

Comment: Is Cambridge, United Kingdom a bird city? If that is not too spoilery, does the answer for Cambridge, England differ?

Comment: @quarague, same answer for both!

Comment: Dumb question, is 'Atalanta' correctly spelled? English language Wikipedia doesn't seem to have a city of that name in Italy.

Comment: @quarague, well spotted, it should be Bergamo haha

Comment: How about "Gotham City - United States of America" and "East Grestin - Arstotzka"?

Comment: @notalentgeek, is East Grestin this city: https://www.google.com/maps/place/East+Grestin/@53.3171603,110.8243979,4.88z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x5c4db589bf169921:0x7388b2828c94c8ef!8m2!3d54.7261242!4d110.9990191?hl=en ?

Comment: No, it is the East Grestin https://papersplease.fandom.com/wiki/Grestin a fictional city.

Comment: @notalentgeek, I added both cities to the hint!

Comment: May I guess that Amsterdam is NOT a Bird City™?

Comment: Since Paris is a Bird City: Was Lutetia one as well? (as in Paris during Roman times)

Comment: @notalentgeek, actually, Amsterdam is a Bird City™ while, unless my history knowledge is not correct, which is surely possible, Lutetia was not!

Comment: Does Mykonos in the question refer to the whole municipality or just the town of Mykonos (also known as Chora)? And whichever it is, is the other one a Bird City™?

Comment: How about West and East Berlin during the Cold War ?

Comment: @xyldke, I did not think of such a difference and it doesn't change for both case, Mykonos remains a Bird City!

Comment: @Auribouros, I added both, I am 99% sure, because that depends on history classes I was not as steady as mathematics or computer science. In comparison, I am 0% sure about East Grestin - Arstotzka.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that Bremen, Germany is a Bird City™, while Glasgow, UK is not?

Comment: @xyldke, well actually, it is the opposite, Bremen is **not** a Bird City™ while Glasgow **is** a Birt City™!

Comment: @notalentgeek, just noticed I did not tell for Gotham and it is now done!

Comment: @JKHA Damn, that removes the one idea I had. I need to think some more about this one.

Comment: Was Brooklyn a bird city in 1897? (it joined New York City in 1898). And just for my curiosity, not as an "official" guess: Was New York already a bird city back then?

Comment: @xyldke, both were Bird Cities in 1897 :)

Comment: Thanks! My interest in past cities has been satisfied for now. Is Roma, Italia a Bird City™?

Comment: Since there is no eastern European Bird City™ yet, what about Moscow?

Comment: Okay I went back to this post to try it again, may I ask to know if the [city of Stormwind](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Stormwind_City) is a Bird city?

Comment: @Auribouros, I forgot about this puzzle haha! I added your city and a second hint ;)

Comment: And no knowledge tag? I must truly just be missing something..

Comment: @Auribouros, indeed, this tag is not appropriated

Comment: The best a friend and I could come up with was fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur fvmr bs pvgvrf/qvfgnaprf, but we didn't get that much farther and are not even sure..

Comment: @Auribouros Vg vf eryngrq gb qvfgnaprf ohg abg pvgl fvmrf

Comment: Bird City is a city in Cheyenne County, Kansas, United States.

Answer (score 1):

After months of going back and forth on this post, I think I have finally solved it.

A Bird City™ is:

> A city in which if you take any two points, the [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) between those two points will never leave the boundaries of the city. It is called a "Bird" city because the geodesic can also be known *as the crow flies*, the shortest distance between two geographical points.

Reasoning:

> I knew it was something about the distance but it didn't click immediately, looking at the shape of the non-Bird cities, I noticed their often awkward shape, and after a quick search of distance between two geographical points, it all came together.

Comment: I don't think Glasgow fits this pattern (look at the neighbourhoods of Castlemilk and Tollcross)